# Why doesnt eclipse data source explorer show h2 v2.1.210 tables?

Tags: eclipse, h2, liquibase

I tried to upgrade from h2 v1.4.200 to v2.1.210, but when I do I can no longer see the tables created in eclipse data source explorer.

The tables are created using liquibase v4.7.1 with this configuration:

```
<configuration>
  <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/master.xml</changeLogFile>
  <promptOnNonLocalDatabase>false</promptOnNonLocalDatabase>
  <driver>org.h2.Driver</driver>
  <url>jdbc:h2:file:~/h2-test;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE</url>
  <username>sa</username>
  <password>sa</password>
</configuration>
```

And this master.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-4.7.xsd">

  <changeSet id="1" author="h2">
    <createTable tableName="test">
      <column name="test_id" type="bigint" autoIncrement="true">
        <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false" />
      </column>
      <column name="name" type="varchar(20)">
        <constraints nullable="false" />
      </column>
      <column name="updated" type="datetime">
        <constraints nullable="false" />
      </column>
    </createTable>
  </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

Using these Generic JDBC Connection Properties:
[image]

I get this result in Eclipse Data Source when I'm using h2 driver v1.4.200:
[image]

But when I upgrade the h2 driver to v2.1.210 and recreate the database, I get this result:
[image]

The tables simply doesn't show.

Is there something I have forgotten in the connection string? Something different that was added in h2 v2? I have tried different versions of the h2 driver, and all versions => 2.0 have the same problem.

I tested using eclipse version 2021-12 (4.22.0)

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse Data Tools Platform doesn't have any special support for H2 Database, that's why it uses a generic implementation. In [JdbcSchema.java](https://git.eclipse.org/c/datatools/org.eclipse.datatools.git/tree/plugins/connectivity/org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.sqm.core/src/org/eclipse/datatools/connectivity/sqm/core/rte/jdbc/JDBCSchema.java?id=4b901a82e51c64bd154e3d34d55976e8e884ff6a#n446) it treats only tables of type `TABLE` and `SYSTEM TABLE` as tables, but regular tables in H2 2.x.y have type `BASE TABLE`. I didn't test it, but it looks like a possible reason of this bug.

You can try to request support of H2 in bugtracker of Data Tools:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi

but Data Tools Platform is not under active development.

There is also a very similar unresolved bug about MariaDB opened in 2019 (but it may have a some different reason):
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=545244

You may need to find some other tools to work with your databases.